# map function is not defined when calling products object in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to display all my products from a fake api to my homescreen. I am using react redux to manage the state. When i console log the products object I get null so i dont think im getting anything from the call.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Product from '../components/product';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import  { listProducts }  from '../actions/productActions';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
  const { products } = productList;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts({}));
  },[dispatch]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row center">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Product key={product.id} product={product}></Product>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
import { PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS } from "../constants/productConstants";

const productListReducer = (
  state= {loading: true, products: [] },
  action
  ) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return{loading:true}
    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS :
        return {loading:false,products:action.payload}
      case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL :
          return {loading:false,error:action.payload}
        default:

        return state
    }
    }
    export default productListReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialy products array is not defined, so you should add a condition like this

```
export default function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
  const { products } = productList;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts({}));
  },[dispatch]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row center">
        {!!products && products.map((product) => (
          <Product key={product.id} product={product}></Product>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```